# First Tech Challenge - Code debugging on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, debugging, robotics

Mentor here to an FTC team.     We need to debug code in Android Studio.    Set breakpoints, inspect variables, etc.

This used to work when they used phones. Now they have different hardware (Control Hub) and there isn't documentation on how to set it up.

Anyone get debugging to work?     Pointers?

Comment: Reminder that while I as able to find: https://ftc-docs.firstinspires.org/en/latest/programming_resources/shared/managing_control_hub/Managing-a-Control-Hub.html#connecting-to-the-control-hub-using-wireless-adb with a quick search "first robotics control hub" you should detail your hardware (w/links if necessary) as well as explain in detail what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks.   Here I am committing the sins that I try to tell the students not to do, i.e., fully RTM - read the manual.   (In my defense, I only parachuted in a week ago...)    They certainly had not done the absolute last thing on that page - will try it out.    Thanks again!